# altering asp:button tag to include an image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, imagebutton

Currently this is how my button tag looks like and this is how i want it to be:

```
 <button class="glossyBtn" type="submit" id="Save" name="Save">
        <img style="vertical-align: middle" alt="" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/blueprint/plugins/buttons/icons/tick.png")%>" />
        <span style="vertical-align: middle">Save</span>
 </button>
```

But i also have an asp:Button tag that i would like to add the same img and span tags but not sure how to alter it. So i can add an icon image to the left of the text of the button.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" ToolTip="Insert" Text="Insert" CssClass="glossyBtn"/>
```

I also have an asp:DynamicHyperLink that i would like to add the image and span features as well to the following:

```
<asp:DynamicHyperLink CssClass="glossyBtn" ID="InsertHyperLink" ToolTip="Add New Item" runat="server" Action="Insert">Add New Item            
                </asp:DynamicHyperLink>
```

Any insightful tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you mixing asp.net mvc and classic asp?

Comment: style + background:url('ur image') ?

Comment: @Yasser when i try adding this to asp:DynamicHyperLink tag or asp:Button, the image doesn't appear. Is there a proper way to embedding an image tag? thanks